# Silverlight: Move the ScrollViewer by code?

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer

I wanna to move the "ScrollViewer" control left and right by buttons outside it, I found this function:

**ScrollViewer.LineLeft()**

It's ok but I wanna to **increase the amount of movement** to left by each click by specific amount like 200 pixel?

There is **another thing**: how I can make my button when hold the mouse on it to duplicate executes it's click event handler until the mouseleftbutton becomes Up (like the buttons of the scroll itself)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can derive your content control from `IScrollInfo` and implement the LineLeft method yourself as you want.

If you just want to jump to a position using other buttons (external to the `ScrollViewer`), you can use the `SetHorizontalOffset` and `SetVerticalOffset` methods.

To make the `Button` to fire Click repeatedly, just replace it by a `RepeatButton`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.repeatbutton(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Regarding my first question I still can't have the control over the scroll viewer movement amount can you give me an example.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo - it's for WPF but most of it applies to SL.